how mysql process select with many value in IN clause
For sql like select * from table where fieldA in (...), if there are lots of values in parentheses(like 1000 values), and there is a B-tree index on fieldA. How mysql execute this sql.
Does it work like foreach(value in values) {select * from table where fieldA=value}, or it has some better way to do it
In this question Is SQL IN bad for performance?. It only says IN predicate is translated into OR predicate. It doesn't tell me what is the execution plan.

This question is similar to: Is SQL IN bad for performance?. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

With respect to MySQL, you should read this manual page about how it optimizes range queries: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/range-optimization.html#equality-range-optimization

That depends on runtime values related to the list of values, the size of the table, and selectivity of the predicate. Sometimes a "Full Table Scan" is faster than a "Index Skip Scan". The optimizer decides which one to use. Look at the plan to find out.

@BillKarwin I have read this artical. But it only say how to calculate the cost of each query. What I want to know is how they execute the query after the cost has been calculated.

it will try to predict the fastest way to execute the query, and use that. It may use an index, it might use a table scan. It depends on the specific values and the cardinality of the index.

Do not reference a Q&A that says "I'm using SQL Server 2000" when talking about a MySQL/MariaDB question!

It depends on the size of the table and values in it. It could be a "full table scan", usually when the number of selected values is rather close to the size of the table or the number of values is very high. Or the index could be used. It really depends on the production data within the table.

I think it also depends on the version of MySQL/MariaDB -- the Optimizer changed IN handling at some point.

Can you elaborate the two ways (full table scan and index scan) mysql use, , better with some pseudocode.

See next experiment.
1.Create table (about 1250 rows) - significant for test.With this size Index seek better then full table scan
2.Run query with IN(...) without{"query_cost": "125.35"} and with index {"query_cost": "19.41"}.
3.See difference.  Query with index is faster than without.
Will the DBMS deploy the condition IN(...) in the sequence (... or ... or ...), or use the index and JOIN, or some other optimization, depends significantly on the availability of indexes and other properties of the database.
create table test (id int ,code varchar(254),description char(200)); 
-- create index ix_code on test (code);
create index ix_id on test (id);
insert into test(id,code,description) values
 (1,'C1','Description1')
 ;
 set @@cte_max_recursion_depth=2000;
 insert into test (id,code,description)
with recursive r as(
  select 1 i,1 id, cast(concat('c',1) as char(50)) code
     ,concat('Description',cast(1 as char(100))) Description 
  from test
  union all
  select i+1 i,cast(round(rand()*1000,0) as signed) id
     ,cast(concat('c',cast(cast(round(rand()*1000,0) as signed) as char(30)))as char(50)) code
     ,cast(concat('Description',i) as char(100)) Description 
  from r
  where i<1250
)
select id,code,description from r;

EXPLAIN FORMAT=JSON 
select * from test
where id in(11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10)
;

Test query
select * from test
where id in(11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10);


Some data about query without index
{
"query_block": {
"select_id": 1,
"cost_info": {"query_cost": "125.35"},
"table": {
"table_name": "test",
"access_type": "ALL",
"rows_examined_per_scan": 1251,
"rows_produced_per_join": 625,
"filtered": "50.00",
"cost_info": {
"read_cost": "62.80",
"eval_cost": "62.55",
"prefix_cost": "125.35",
"data_read_per_join": "1M"
},
"used_columns": ["id","code","description"],
"attached_condition": "(`sandbox_db`.`test`.`id` in (11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10))"
}

With index
{
"query_block": {
"select_id": 1,
"cost_info": {
"query_cost": "19.41"
},
"table": {
"table_name": "test",
"access_type": "range",
"possible_keys": ["ix_id"],
"key": "ix_id",
"used_key_parts": ["id"],
"key_length": "5",
"rows_examined_per_scan": 32,
"rows_produced_per_join": 32,
"filtered": "100.00",
"index_condition": "(`sandbox_db`.`test`.`id` in (11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10))",
"cost_info": {
"read_cost": "16.21",
"eval_cost": "3.20",
"prefix_cost": "19.41",
"data_read_per_join": "57K"
},
"used_columns": ["id","code","description"]
}

Fiddle
